# Dojo Combobox won't open properly when a Dialogwindow is open

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo, dialog

While I have opend a Dialogwindow, i cant open the Comboboxes we use properly.
Normaly you just click and it pops up, but in this case you need to hold the Mouse
to open the Menu and choose an object.

When I close the dialog, everything works normal.

Have anybody faces the same Problem? We tried to change the Index of the dialog, disable the widgets inside and change the theme ( in our case claro ) but nothing changes this behaviour.

The dialog and the comboboxes are setup programmatic.

```
var dialCont =  "<div id='EditorBarDiv'></div><br /><div id='TempPickDiv'></div>";
        dialCont += "<div style='position:absolute;top:75px;left:320px;width:190px;height:300px;'>";
        ...
        dialCont += "<br /><br /><button data-dojo-type='dijit/form/Button' type='button' onClick='javascript:makeFlaeche();'>Erzeugen</button><div>";

        drawKieWoDialog = new Dialog({
             title: "Eventareas",
             id:"DKiWo",
            content: dialCont,
            style: "width: 600px;height:550px;overflow:auto;z-index:-1000"
        });
        drawKieWoDialog.show();
```

UPDATE:

It seems the dialog blocks the focus to all other widget.

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Which browser are you using? And which version of Dojo? I tried to reproduce it, but could not: http://jsfiddle.net/9nobaemx/

Comment: Hi! We use Firefox newest Version, IE 10 and dojo 1.10 and esris javascript api 3.10. I guess it's a Problem with the dialog window but i'm not sure. It's not a Problem with Comboboxes inside the dialog, but outside. We have a Menu with AccordionPanes and Comboboxes inside, and these Comboboxes won't work properly when the dialog opends.Have a look here http://ims.kiel.de/extern/kielmaps/ Open the Printwindow and then try to use the combobox at the left side. Then you can see what i mean

Comment: Ah, I see you are using the underlay trick to avoid the dialog being modal. I've had a lot of problems with that too, I guess dijit/Dialog is not indented to be used as non-modal. Have you looked at dojox/layout/FloatingPane ? Perhaps that can be used instead.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip with the floatingPane Frode! That solves the Problem!